# Is there a shell that checks to make sure the code is signed?

Tags: linux, scripting, security

I was messing around with PowerShell this week and discovered that you are required to Sign your scripts so that they can be run.  Is there any similar secure functionality in Linux that relates to preventing bash scripts from being run?

The only functionality similar to this, that I'm aware of is that of SSH requiring a certain key.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an ad-hoc solution to package signing to me.  I don't know if Windows has cryptographic package signing the way Linux has.

Comment: @Wildcard it's just for scripting; not writing entire software packages...

Comment: @leeand00 A script is a special case of a software package and I can't see any point to singling out that case.

Comment: The mechanism I'm most fond of is the way ChromeOS does this -- putting the only filesystem not flagged `noexec` on a read-only partition on a dm-verity signed block device.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay, you're going to have to unpack that for me Charles...link?

Comment: https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/ talks about Android's adoption of that (initially ChromeOS) feature.

Comment: You can consider bash as a bunch of commands that can be typed manual in command line interface. What's the point to restrict the scripts when you can type the contents in command line anyway?

Comment: You've tagged and mentioned bash, but there are other shells available; is your question specific to bash, or general to any scripting shell in Linux?

Comment: @JeffSchaller well I was assuming bash but if you have something better let me know about it.

Comment: I think this question is pretty vague. Are you wanting a shell that does this on execution, on download through a repository (apt/npm esque), a kernel, a module, or executable format?

Comment: @EvanCarroll On execution, that's the way it works in Powershell, so you can make sure nobody screwed with your script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're locking users' ability to run scripts via `sudo` then you could use the `digest` functionality.
You can specify the hash of a script/executable in `sudoers` which will be verified by `sudo` before being executed. So although not the same as signing, it gives you a basic guarantee that the script has at least not been modified without sudoers also being modified.

> If a command name is prefixed with a Digest_Spec, the command will only match successfully if it can be verified using the specified SHA-2 digest. This may be useful in situations where the user invoking sudo has write access to the command or its parent directory. The following digest formats are supported: sha224, sha256, sha384 and sha512. The string may be specified in either hex or base64 format (base64 is more compact). There are several utilities capable of generating SHA-2 digests in hex format such as openssl, shasum, sha224sum, sha256sum, sha384sum, sha512sum.

http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html

Comment: That'll hold me over until I read about SE Linux and do it right.

Answer (score 13):

Yes and no.

Linux software distribution works somewhat differently from Windows software distribution. In the (non-embedded) Linux world, the primary method to distribute software is via a distribution (Ubuntu, Debian, RHEL, Fedora, Arch, etc.). All major distributions have been signing their packages systematically for about a decade.

When software is distributed independently, it's up to the vendor to decide how they'll ship their software. Good vendors provide package sources that's compatible with the major distributions (there's no unified distribution mechanism for all of Linux: software distribution is one of the main points of differentiation between distributions) and that are signed with the vendor's key. Linux distributions rarely act as a signing authority for third-party vendors (Canonical does this with Ubuntu partners, but that covers very few vendors), and I think all major distributions use the PGP web of trust rather than the TLS public key infrastructure, so it's up to the user to figure out whether they want to trust a key.

There's no special mechanism that singles out software packages that consist of a single script from software packages that consist of a native executable, a data file, or multiple files. Nor is any signature verification built into any common script interpreter, because verifying a software package is a completely orthogonal concern from running a script.

I think Windows annotates files with their origin, and requires user confirmation to run a file whose origin is “downloaded” rather than “local”. Linux doesn't really have a similar mechanism. The closest thing is execution permission: a downloaded file does not have execution permission, the user needs to explicitly enable it (`chmod +x` on the command line, or the equivalent action in a file manager).

Comment: FWIW, on top of this PowerShell can be configured (by policy settings) to only execute _signed_ scripts and this policy can be configured so that _all_ scripts must be signed or only "remote origin" scripts, or no scripts.  It works best in an AD environment with key management and central policy management.  It _can_ be bypassed :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris Well yeah if you set It to bypass...

Comment: @leeand00 - Apparently base64 encoding also works as a bypass but I don't know if that's been closed in newer versions of PowerShell.

Comment: @StephenHarris whoa what?!?  Which old version does that?!??

Comment: @leeand00 - see http://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2013/3/5/powershell-basics-execution-policy-part-1.html for some fun :-)  Basically pass the base64 encoded script as a parameter on the command line :-)  Easy enough to wrapper!

Comment: SeLinux annotates files with their origin. It's one of its main premises.

Answer (score 10):

Linux does not provide the capability to limit the execution of bash scripts based on digital signatures.

There is some work on authenticating binary executables. See https://lwn.net/Articles/488906/ for info.

Comment: Upvote for direct answer without suggesting a hackey work-around.

Answer (score 8):

In a word, "no".

Linux doesn't really differentiate between executables and scripts; the `#!` at the beginning is a way to tell the kernel what program to run to evaluate the input but it's not the only way a script can be executed.

So, for example, if I have a script

```
$ cat x
#!/bin/sh 
echo hello
```

Then I can run this with the command

```
$ ./x
```

That will cause the kernel to try and execute it, spot the `#!` and then effectively run `/bin/sh x` instead.

However I could *also* run any of these variants as well:

```
$ sh ./x
$ bash ./x
$ cat x | sh
$ cat x | bash
$ sh < x
```

or even

```
. ./x
```

So even if the kernel tried to enforce signing at the `exec` layer we can bypass this by only running the interpreter with the script as a parameter.

This means that signing code would have to be in the interpreter itself.  And what would stop a user from compiling their own copy of a shell *without* the signing enforcement code?

The standard solution to this isn't to use signing, but to use Mandatory Access Controls (MAC), such as `SELinux`.  With MAC systems you can specify exactly what each user is allowed to run and transition layers.  So, for example, you can say "normal users can run anything but the web server and CGI processes can only access stuff from the `/var/httpd` directory; everything else is rejected".

Comment: `This means that signing code would have to be in the interpreter itself. And what would stop a user from compiling their own copy of a shell without the signing enforcement code?` Not allowing executing of *any* unsigned executables would do it, If the user doesn't have the signing key.  There are various *nix projects for this already.

Answer (score 2):

Linux distros usually have **gnupg**. It sounds to me like all you want is a simple bash wrapper that checks a detached gpg signature against the argument script and only proceeds to run the script if the check succeeds:

```
#!/bin/sh
gpgv2 $1.asc && bash "$@"
```

Comment: The only thing this doesn't present is running a script that somebody just made...on their own...

Answer (score 2):

The counter-question that comes to mind immediately is "Why would you ever want to prevent users from running programs *they wrote?*" Several possibilities exist:

1. It is literally impossible to detect **who authored the code in the first place.** The owner of the script file is just whoever actually saved the content of that file, regardless of where it came from. So enforcing a signature is just a complicated **substitute for a confirmation dialogue box:** "Are you sure you want to do this?" In Linux part of this problem is solved transparently with signed packages, and mitigated by the fact that users have limited access by default. The user is also expected to know that running others' code can be dangerous*.
2. In the same vein signing a script is a much more complex operation than saving a file. In the best case this prompts the user to realise that they are performing an action similar to signing a document, and should inspect what it says before continuing. Most likely it simply ensures a very minimal level of **technical proficiency** on the part of the user to be allowed to run the script. In the worst case it demonstrates a willingness to jump through a long series of **hoops** to run what they wanted to. Technical proficiency is assumed on Linux*.
3. It is more likely that people will **detect obviously malicious code** when typing/pasting a series of commands to their command line. Plaintext snippets meant to be copied and pasted usually are smaller than the series of commands necessary to do something properly nefarious. The user can also carefully copy and paste every line separately, understanding what happens as it happens. With a script it's possible the user has never looked at the code at all. This may be a useful application of signed scripts, at the all-too-common cost of complacency after the 12th time you have to do it.

* This is probably becoming less and less true as more people start using Linux

Answer (score 2):

The reason the systems have evolved differently is that Linux has the 'exec' file attribute and Windows uses file extensions to determine executability.

So in Windows it's easy to trick the user into downloading a file with an ".exe", ".bat", ".scr" extension, *which will be hidden by default*. Double-clicking that file would give you arbitary code execution. Hence a large mechanism of origin tracking and executable / script signing was built to mitigate this risk.

On Linux, you might be able to get a file to the user, but you can't easily force the 'exec' bit to be set. Additionally, it's possible to make entire filesystems 'noexec'.

You can in any case run a script explicitly by invoking the interpreter. You can even create shell scripts at runtime and pipe them into "sh", or run "sh -c".

Answer (score 0):

By custom, many archiving programs do not preserve execute bit on contained files. This makes it impossible to run arbitrary executables. Well almost.

The point is, what was described in another answer that lack of execute bit doesn't prevent you from passing such script directly to `bash`. While it's arguable that most such scripts are `bash` scripts, the shebang can specify any program as interpreter. This means that it's up to the user to run appropriate interpreter if they decide to ignore the executable semantics.

While this isn't much, this pretty much covers prevention of running untrusted executables on *nixes *with just kernel and shell*.

As I mentioned in one of the comments, there is one other layer of protection -- `SeLinux` -- which tracks the origin of files based on a set of rules. A set up `SeLinux` would not for example allow root to run an executable with executable bit set that was downloaded from the internet, even if you copy and move the file around. One can add a rule that such files can only be run through another binary that would check the signature, not unlike what you mentioned in your question.

So, in the end it's a matter of configuration of commonly preinstalled tools, and the answer is **yes**.

Comment: *many archiving programs do not preserve execute bit on contained files* .. well, that's kind of a handicap when you actually want to use it for archiving. Fortunately `tar` *does* preserve the execute bit.

Comment: You have to use `tar -p` [source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463325/what-does-tars-p-preserve-permissions-flag-actually-preserve&ved=0ahUKEwj_vu6nhrTOAhUKhiwKHUhFD3kQFgghMAM&usg=AFQjCNEqWzVEvGjPeOIIrJABTsvXZDfD1Q&sig2=umschEBz39B66c2FDIwsiA)

Comment: `-p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions` means 
extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)

Comment: No, you do NOT need -p. I see what the man page says, but it's not what happens. `touch permtest; chmod +x permtest; tar cf permtest.tar.gz permtest; rm permtest; tar xf permtest.tar.gz; ls -l permtest` - it's executable here, and I'm not root.

Comment: I'll try to improve my answer then.